# Does the Ropecaster's Tear stat affect immobilization?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

In the same vein as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/301749/50264), does adding a +Tear modifier to a Ropecaster have any effect on its primary function of immobilizing machines?

For example, is it possible for a tie rope to, say, bounce off of heavily armored enemies unless you add to its Tear stat?

Answer (score 1):

After having an unmodded ropecaster versus a heavily modded ropecaster, I'd say there is no difference.  However, each shot does do damage, and heavily tear modding your rope caster will significantly reduce the time it takes to kill larger enemies that take a lot of rope (Stormbirds being the great example).